# GKE RBAC role / rolebinding to access node status in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't get a rolebinding right in order to get node status from an app which runs in a pod on GKE.

I am able to create a pod from there but not get node status. Here is the role I am creating:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: node-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

This is the error I get when I do a getNodeStatus:

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "nodes \"gke-cluster-1-default-pool-36c26e1e-2lkn\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:sa-poc\" cannot get nodes/status at the cluster scope: Unknown user \"system:serviceaccount:default:sa-poc\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {
        "name": "gke-cluster-1-default-pool-36c26e1e-2lkn",
        "kind": "nodes"
    },
    "code": 403
}
```

I tried with some minor variations but did not succeed.

Kubernetes version on GKE is 1.8.4-gke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subresource permissions are represented as `<resource>/<subresource>`, so in the role, you would specify `resources: ["nodes","nodes/status"]`